# SQL group data (find data family)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help me, I need to find out a SQL solution for grouping data using SQL Server database.
I'm pretty sure that it could be done in one SQL request but I can't see the trick.

Let' see the problem :
I have a two columns table (please see below an example). I just want to add a new column containing a number or a string which indicates the group

BEFORE :

```
Col1 | Col2
-----+-----
A    | B
B    | C
D    | E
F    | G
G    | H
I    | I
J    | U
```

AFTER TRANSFORMATION :

```
Col1 | Col2 | Group
-----+------+------
A    | B    | 1
B    | C    | 1
D    | E    | 2
F    | G    | 3
G    | H    | 3
I    | I    | 4
J    | U    | 5
```

In other words: A, B, C are in the same group; D and E too; F, G, H in group 3 ....

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any lookup table to get this group mapping?
Or if you just have a logic defined to decide a group, i would recommend to add a `UDF` which will return group for supplied values.

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,GetGroupID(Col1,Col2) AS Group
FROM Table
```

Your `UDF` will be something like following

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetGroupID
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Col1 varchar(10),
    @Col2 varchar(10)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @groupID int

      IF (@Col1="A" AND @Co2 = "B") OR (@Col1="B" AND @Co2 = "C")
      BEGIN
         SET @groupID = 1
      END
      IF @Col1="D" AND @Co2 = "E"
      BEGIN
         SET @groupID = 2
      END
       -- You can write saveral conditions in the same manner.
    return @groupID
END
```

However, in case you have this mapping defined somewhere in another table, let us know the structure of the table and we can then update the query to join with that table instead of using `UDF`.

Considering the performance of the query, if the amount of data is huge in your table , it is recommended to have these mappings to one fix table and Join that table in query. Using UDF may harm performance if data amount is huge.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer.
I was thinking about a solution close to this one using UDF but I'm afraid of the amount of data (about 180 million lines - all the accounting data of a big company covering 2 fiscal years).

I have only one table to process (2 columns, each one containing one primary key pointing to 2 others tables).


Could you please tell me what you would write in the BEGIN/DECLARE clause  ?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need for a `UDF` here.  Regardless of whether you are looking to update the table with a new column or simply pull out the data with the grouping applied, you will be best off using a set based solution, ie: create and join to a table.

*I am assuming here that you don't have messy data, such as a row with `Col1 = 'A'` and `Col2 = 'F'`.*

If you are able to add new tables permanently you can use the following to create your lookup table:

```
create table Col1Groups(Col1 nvarchar(10), GroupNum int);
insert into Col1Groups(Col1,GroupNum) values ('A',1),('B',1),('C',1),('D',2),('E',2),('F',3),('G',3),('H',3);
```

and then `join` to it:

```
select t.Col1
      ,t.Col2
      ,g.GroupNum
from Table t
    inner join Col1Groups g
        on t.Col1 = g.Col1
```

If you can't, you can just create a derived table via a `CTE`:

```
with Col1Groups as
(
    select Col1
          ,GroupNum
    from (values('A',1),('B',1),('C',1),('D',2),('E',2),('F',3),('G',3),('H',3)) as x(Col1,GroupNum)
)
select t.Col1
      ,t.Col2
      ,g.GroupNum
from Table t
    inner join Col1Groups g
        on t.Col1 = g.Col1
```

Comment: The problem is to *find* the groups. If you want to do this manually, this is going to be some work, as the OP talks about about 180 million rows in a comment to the other answer. Also your values clause may become rather large ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  Well, yes.  But then that needs to be done whatever the solution.  If there are thousands and thousands of groupings then they will definitely be best served creating a permanent lookup table.

Comment: Well, the groups are implicit; we can see from the data which records belong to a group. So best would be to either get group identifiers on-the-fly or to change the whole table design in order to avoid redundancy if possible.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  If that is the case, you would need to either make more assumptions or add logic to check for overlapping groups.  What would you do if there was a row with `Col1 = 'A' and Col2 = 'F'`?

Comment: That would make F and all that belongs to it part of the A group, as I see it. You are right, however, there is no sample data for a duplicate col1, so we don't really know what rule applies in such a case (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You get the first rows per group with

```
select col1, col2 from mytable where col1 not in (select col2 from mytable) or col1 = col2;
```

We can give these rows numbers with

```
rank() over (order by col1) as grp
```

Now we must iterate through the rows to find the ones belonging to those first ones, then those belonging to these, etc. A recursive query.

```
with cte(col1, col2, grp) as 
(
  select col1, col2, rank() over (order by col1) as grp
  from mytable where col1 not in (select col2 from mytable) or col1 = col2
  union all
  select mytable.col1, mytable.col2, cte.grp
  from cte
  join mytable on mytable.col1 = cte.col2
  where mytable.col1 <> mytable.col2
)
select * from cte
order by grp, col1;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but it doesn't work for that dataset for example :
Col1 Col2
A B
B C
D E
F G
G H
I I
J U
A Z
SDF Z
I T

The result built from your script :
A B 1
B C 1
A Z 2
D E 3
F G 4
G H 4
J U 5
SDF Z 6

'I' is missing ...

Comment: I didn't consider the case when col1 = col2; so the query is incomplete. However, in your new example there are suddenly duplicate col1, which makes this quite a different task. Fortunately we can solve this by using `RANK` rather than `ROW_NUMBER`. I'll update my answer accordingly. Please don't come up with duplicate col2 now :-) That could not be solved with my query and would better be asked in a separate request then.

Answer (score 0):

**Additional answer for a more flexible approach**

---

Originally you asked for chains A|B -> B|C, F|G -> G|H etc., but in your comment to my other answer you introduced forks like A|B -> B|C, B|D and I've adjusted my answer.

If you want to go one step further and introduce net-like relations such as A|B -> B|C, D|C, we can no longer follow chains forward only (in the example D belongs to the A group, because though A doesn't lead to D directly, it leads to C and D also leads to C. Here is a way to solve this:

Get all letters from the table (no matter whether in col1 or col2). Then for each of them find related letters (again no matter whether in col1 or col2). And for these again find related letters and so on. That will give you complete groups. But duplicates (as D is in the A group, A is in the D group also), which you can get rid of by simply taking the smallest (or greatest) group key per letter. Then join the Groups to the table.

The query:

```
with cte(col, grp) as 
(
  select col, rownum as grp from 
    (select col1 as col from mytable union select col2 from mytable)
  union all
  select case when mytable.col1 = cte.col then mytable.col2 else mytable.col1 end, cte.grp
  from cte
  join mytable on cte.col in (mytable.col1, mytable.col2) 
  where mytable.col1 <> mytable.col2
)
cycle col set is_cycle to 'y' default 'n'
select mytable.col1, mytable.col2, x.grp 
from mytable
join (select col, min(grp) as grp from cte group by col) x on x.col = mytable.col1
order by grp, col;
```